# Euler-Cauchy equation boundary conditions problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

ODE:

$$xy''+2y'+ax=0$$

BCs:
$$y(0)=\alpha$$
$$y'(L)=0$$

ODE solution:
$$y(x)=-\frac{ax^2}{6}+\frac{c_1}{x}+c_2$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}y(x)=\infty\Rightarrow c_1=0$$
$$y'(x)=-\frac{ax}{3}$$
With $c_2$ dropping out, it cannot be determined from the second BC?

And yet we can determine $c_2$ from the 1st BC:

$$y(0)=c_2=\alpha$$

So why does the second BC seem redundant?

Comment: Note that $x = 0$ is a singular point of your ODE, and you don't always have the "freedom" you expect to impose BCs at singular points.  For example, there are no non-trivial solutions of the ODE $x^2 y' +x y' - y = 0$ that satisfy $y(0) = 0$.  (The general solution is $y = c_1 x + c_2/x$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not going to have any solutions. Your ODE solution is correct. To get $y(0)=\alpha$ requires $c_1=0,$ as you have pointed out. You would end up with
$$y(x)=\frac{6\alpha-ax^2}{6}.$$
Then
$$y'(x)=-\frac{ax}{3},$$
as you also pointed out. But this cannot satisfy $y'(L)=0$ unless you have the overly restrictive criterion that $a=0.$

If you allow a corner point, you might be able to satisfy all the BCs, but the solution would, of course, not be differentiable at the corner.

I wouldn't call your second BC redundant, but inconsistent with the ODE and the first BC.